# not able to modify javascript object which i get from input tag

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload, javascript-objects

i am trying to make upload functionality in my e-commerce website and in my html i have created
`<input type="file" id="file" accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg, .svg, .jfif, pjpeg, pjp" multiple><br>` which gives me a object of items and i am trying to modify the files name within this object but couldn't able to do that please help

**HTML**

```
<form id="form">
        <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Product Name"><br>
        <input type="number" id="price" placeholder="Price"><br>
        <textarea id="description" placeholder="Description" name="description" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
        <input type="file" id="file" accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg, .svg, .jfif, pjpeg, pjp" multiple><br>
        <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
    </form>
```

**JS**

```
const button = document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    let userFiles = document.getElementById("file").files;
    
    let i = 1;
    for (let element of userFiles) {
        // console.log(element.type)
        let extension = element.type.slice(6,element.type.length+1);
        console.log("user_file"+i+"."+extension);
        element.name = "user_file"+i+"."+extension;
        console.log(element["name"]);
        i++;
    }
 

});
```

i want to change the name of uploaded files in the format "user_file`i`.extension"

Comment: As explained by David you can't change the filename in the file object. But you can change the file name when processing the POST formdata (e.g via php)

Comment: ohh but i don't know php i am beginer btw thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. But how are you processing the files? Since, you need to save/transfer files to the server, you'll need some sort of server-side script once the form was submitted (no matter which language/environment you're using). Maybe you could add some details about the current form submission process.

Answer (score 2):

The `files` property of the `HTMLInputElement`'s interface returns a `FileList` object containing `File` objects and *all* properties of a `File` object are *read-only*, they therefor cannot be changed.

See:
[MDN FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)
[MDN File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)